# How to tell Gradle to get sources from project instead of sources jar when adding project dependency?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, intellij-idea, kotlin-multiplatform

I have an Android library module that depends on a Kotlin Multiplatform module via project dependency. My issue is that when I try to go to the source of a class, it takes me to the imported sources jar instead of the project that I am depending on. Is it possible to have it take me to the project's source instead of to the sources artifact? My setup:

*android-local/build.gradle.kts*

```
dependencies {
    api(project(":android-remote", "jvmDefault"))
}
```

I don't know if this is possible with the multiplatform plugin, but thought I would ask just in case.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get this working correctly first I had to add Kotlin's multiplatform plugin to my Android library module. Then I used the `jvmDefault` configuration in my dependencies instead of hooking up a specific Android target in my MP project. Here is the build file for my `android-local` now:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform")
}

android {
    //setup
}

kotlin {
    android()

    sourceSets {
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                api(project(":android-remote", "jvmDefault"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And now I can go to sources in the `android-remote` project (which is a MPP). A bit unintuitive, but it works.